# Check to see if derived class defines a specific instance variable, throw error from metaclass if not

Tags: python, oop, metaclass

So I know that metaclasses provide us with a way to hook into the initialization of class objects in Python. I can use this to check if a derived class instantiates an expected method, like so:

```py
class BaseMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, body):
        print(cls, name, bases, body)
        if name != 'Base' and 'bar' not in body:
            raise TypeError("bar not defined in derived class")
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, body)

class Base(metaclass=BaseMeta):
    def foo(self):
        return self.bar()

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = '/path/to/locality'

    def bar(self):
        return 'bar'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(Derived().foo())
```

In this example, the metaclass raises a TypeError if the Derived class does not define a method which the Base class expects.

What I'm trying to figure out is if I can implement a similar check to the instance variables of the Derived class. I.E. can I use a metaclass to check to see if the `self.path` variable is defined in the Derived class? And, if not, throw a explicit error saying something like `"self.path" was not defined in Derived class as a file path`.

Comment: In Python, instance variables aren't actually defined anywhere: they come into existence when a method of the class (typically `.__init__()` assigns to them.  There's no reliable way to tell what the instance variables are going to be, without actually instantiating the class.

Comment: To add to @jasonharper's comment, if an instance attribute is defined in another method than `__init__`, even initializing an instance will not create the attribute.

Comment: Python isn't like C++, which requires you to declare all the member functions and variables when defining the class.

Comment: ^ That would seem to mean that if the variable is declared in the body of the class, I should be able to hook into it from the metaclass? Instead of defining `self.path` in `__init__()` have `path` defined directly in `Derived`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Normal" instance variables, such as the ones taught since Python 2 early days can't be checked at class creation time - all instance variables are dynamically created when the `__init__` (or other) method is executed.

However, since Python 3.6 it is possible to "annotate" variables in the class body - these usually serve only as a hint for static type checking tools, which, in turn, do nothing when the program is actually run.

However, when annotating an attribute in the class body, without providing an initial value (which would then create it as a "class attribute"), it will show in the namespace inside the `__annotations__` key (and not as a key themselves).

In short: you can design a metaclass requiring an attribute to be annotated in the class body, although you can't ensure it is actually filled-in with a value inside `__init__` before it is actually run. (But it can be checked *after* it is called the first time - check the second part of this answer).

All in all - you'd need something like this:

```py
class BaseMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        print(cls, name, bases, namespace)
        if name != 'Base' and (
            '__annotations__' not in namespace or 
            'bar' not in namespace['__annotations__']
        ):
            raise TypeError("bar not annotated in derived class body")
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, namespace)

class Base(metaclass=BaseMeta):
    def foo(self):
        return self.bar

class Derived(Base):
    bar: int
    def __init__(self):
        self.path = '/path/to/locality'
        self.bar = 0
```

If `bar: int` is not present in the derived class body, the metaclass will raise. However, if `self.bar = 0` is not present inside `__init__`, the metaclass has no way to "know" it - not without running the code.

## Close things present in the language

There has been for sometime in Python "abstractclasses" - they
do almost exactly what your first example proposes: one can mandate
that derived classes implement methods with a certain name. However,
this check is made when the class is first *instantiated*, not when
it is created. (Thus allowing more than one level of abstract classes inheriting one from another, and that works as far as none of those
is instantiated):

```py
In [68]: from abc import ABC, abstractmethod                                                                  

In [69]: class Base(ABC): 
    ...:     def foo(self): 
    ...:         ... 
    ...:     @abstractmethod 
    ...:     def bar(self): pass 
    ...:                                                                                                      

In [70]: class D1(Base): pass                                                                                 

In [71]: D1()                                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-1689c9d98c94> in <module>
----> 1 D1()

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class D1 with abstract methods bar

In [72]: class D2(Base): 
    ...:     def bar(self): 
    ...:         ... 
    ...:                                                                                                      

In [73]: D2()                                                                                                 
Out[73]: <__main__.D2 at 0x7ff64270a850>
```

And then, along with "abstractmethods", the ABC bases (which are implemented with a metaclass not unlike the one in your example, although they do have some support in the language core), it is possible to declare "abstractproperties"  - these are declared as class *attributes*, and will raise an error on class instantiation (just like above), if the derived class do not override the attribute. The main difference to the "annotations" approach above is that this actually requires a value to be set on the attribute on the class body, where as the `bar: int` declaration do not create an actual class attribute:

```py
In [75]: import abc                                                                                           

In [76]: class Base(ABC): 
    ...:     def foo(self): 
    ...:         ... 
    ...:     bar = abc.abstractproperty() 
    ...:      
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                                                      

In [77]: class D1(Base): pass                                                                                 

In [78]: D1()                                                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-1689c9d98c94> in <module>
----> 1 D1()

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class D1 with abstract methods bar

In [79]: class D2(Base): 
    ...:     bar = 0 
    ...:                                                                                                      

In [80]: D2()
```

I undestand this may not be desirable - but I called the attention to the natural "instantiation time" error-raising, in these cases, because it is possible to do a..

#... Check instance attribute *after* `__init__` run for the first time.

In this approach, the check is only performed when the class is instantiated, not when it is declared - and consists in wrapping `__init__` in a decorator that will check for the required attributes after it is run for the first time:

```py
from functools import wraps

class BaseMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        # Overides __init__ instead of __new__: 
        # we process "cls" after it was created.
        wrapped = cls.__init__
        sentinel = object()
        @wraps(wrapped)
        def _init_wrapper(self, *args, **kw):
            wrapped(self, *args, **kw)
            errored = []
            for attr in cls._required:
                if getattr(self, attr, sentinel) is sentinel:
                    errored.append(attr)
            if errored:
                raise TypeError(f"Class {cls.__name__} did not set attribute{'s' if len(errored) > 1 else ''} {errored} when instantiated")
            # optionally "unwraps" __init__ after the first instance is created:
            cls.__init__ = wrapped
        if cls.__name__ != "Base":
            cls.__init__ = _init_wrapper
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
```

And checking that in the interactive mode:

```py
In [84]: class Base(metaclass=BaseMeta): 
    ...:     _required = ["bar"] 
    ...:     def __init__(self): 
    ...:         pass 
    ...:                                                                                                      

In [85]: class Derived(Base): 
    ...:     def __init__(self): 
    ...:         pass 
    ...:                                                                                                      

In [86]: Derived()                                                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-8da841e1a3d5> in <module>
----> 1 Derived()

<ipython-input-83-8bf317642bf5> in _init_wrapper(self, *args, **kw)
     13                     errored.append(attr)
     14             if errored:
---> 15                 raise TypeError(f"Class {cls.__name__} did not set attribute{'s' if len(errored) > 1 else ''} {errored} when instantiated")
     16             # optionally "unwraps" __init__ after the first instance is created:
     17             cls.__init__ = wrapped

TypeError: Class Derived did not set attribute ['bar'] when instantiated

In [87]: class D2(Base): 
    ...:     def __init__(self): 
    ...:         self.bar = 0 
    ...:                                                                                                      

In [88]: D2()                                                                                                 
Out[88]: <__main__.D2 at 0x7ff6418e9a10>
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you for posting this I definitely learned a lot. :)

A few followup questions if you don't mind:

Comment: First, is there a reason that I'm missing for, in pt 2, not wrapping `errored` into a list comprehension? My intuition would be to refactor those few lines to `errored_attributes=attr for attr in cls._required_attributes if hasattr(self, attr) is False]`.

Comment: Second, it would appear that this approach can be similarly mapped to check for errored methods via `errored_methods=[method for method in cls._required_methods if hasattr(self, method) is False]`. Any reason to consider not using this wrapping method for catching all of the derived class enforcement errors?

Comment: As for the list comprehension - yes, it can be done like that. I wrote a for loop that would raise on the first error, and when I changed it to collect all errors, I simply did not rewrite it as a comprehension. And also in the second case -a comprehension is equally good.

Comment: The one thing to watch, I did not consider in the code above is chcking the presence of a `_required` attribute in various levels in a class hierarchy, and also, having the "Base" class name hardcoded in the metaclass - those would be nice in production code - but I opted to keep them fixed in the example to keep it simpler.